# Plotting incompatible numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I have two numpy arrays of identical length (398 rows), with the first 5 values for each as follows:

```
y_predicted = 
 [[-0.85908649]
 [-1.19176482]
 [-0.93658361]
 [-0.83557211]
 [-0.80681243]]

y_norm =
            mpg
0     -0.705551
1     -1.089379
2     -0.705551
3     -0.961437
4     -0.833494
```

That is, the first has square brackets around each value, and the second has indexing and no square brackets.

The data is a normalised version of the first column (MPG) of the Auto-MPG dataset. The y_predicted values are results of a linear regression.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data

Would anyone know how I might convert these arrays to the same type so I can plot a scatter plot of them?

Both have shape: (398, 1) 
Both have type: class 'numpy.ndarray', dtype float64

---

Data from the link provided

```
18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1    "buick skylark 320"
18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1    "plymouth satellite"
16.0   8   304.0      150.0      3433.      12.0   70  1    "amc rebel sst"
17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1    "ford torino"
15.0   8   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70  1    "ford galaxie 500"
```

Comment: The output you are showing is too ambiguous to tell what is actually going on in your data. Can you give more info, like the array types, shapes and where they come from?

Comment: Whats the `dtype` attribute of the arrays?

Comment: Is this exactly what you see when you print `y_predicted[:5]` and `y_norm[:5]`? If the second array has a shape `(398, 1)`, then each of these, `0     -0.705551`, is one element. What is that, a string? Also, we didn't ask for `type(y_predicted)`, but for `y_predicted.dtype`.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately this isn't a discusion forum or a code writing service: please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Both are dtype "float64"

Indeed, y_predicted[:5] and y_norm[:5] print as above, although the title of the column is included for y_norm (I've now edited above to make clear).

Comment: You have shown us the data but not how `y_predicted` and `y_norm` are made. what exactly are they?

Answer (score 0):

The second of these looks like a `pandas` `Series` to me. If so you can do `y_norm.values` to get the underlying `numpy` array.